# Querying Class not showing results when called

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a Class to make queries, anywhere across my pages by simply calling the function and adding a `$sql` parameter to the method.

Everything is in a tasting stage so I am aware small issues like SQL injections but thats not the topic here.

After crating the class I tested it but I get no results dont know why as things look good to me, but I might be missing something fundomential.

My PHP calss:

```
<?php

class Query{

    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $user = 'root';
    protected $pass = 'root';
    protected $db = 'test';

    public function connectAction(){

        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db) or die('Cannot Connect to DB');
        return $con;
    }

    public function queryAction($sql){

        mysqli_query($this->connectAction(),$sql);
        //$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);


        /*if($query == true && $count > 0){

        }else{

        }*/

    }
}

$execute = new Query();
```

My Second file where I am trying to Display the results:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<h3><?php

require_once('query.php');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user';

    $execute->queryAction($sql);

    foreach($execute as $item){
        echo $item['user_pass'];
    }

?></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Can some one help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to object:

```
protected $results;
```

in queryAction function change row to:

```
$this->results = mysqli_query($this->connectAction(),$sql);
```

and than:

```
foreach ($execute->results as $result){}
```

Comment: This worked for me I just had to change $result object form protected to public :)

Comment: of course! protected its give an access only for children in inheritance

Comment: Yep I know just though I let you know hehe. once again thank you would up vote you but need 15 reputation points xD

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

Function:

```
function select_rows($table,$fieldlist,$condition)
{
    $sql="select $fieldlist from $table $condition ";
/// echo $sql;exit;
    $resArray=$this->QueryResult($sql,'Select');
    return ($resArray);
}//end function

//function for execute query
function QueryResult($sql,$PVal)
{
    if($sql!=NULL)
    {
        //$rs=mysql_query($sql, $this->dblink) or die(mysql_error().':'.$PVal);
        $rs=mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$rs)
        {
            return $this->MysqlError($PVal);
        }//end if
        else
        { 
            return $rs;
        }//end else
    }//end if
    else
    {
        return '<b>MySQL Error</b>: Empty Query!';
    }//end else
}//end function

//function for print error msg
function MysqlError($eVal)
{
    if(mysql_error()!= '')
    {
            echo mysql_error().$eVal.;
    }//end if
}//end funciton
```

Usage:

```
$cond="condition";
$pass_select=$objA->select_rows(TABLEPREFIX.'tablename','fields',$cond);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function connectAction()
{
    if(!$this->con)
    {
        $this->con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db) or die('Cannot Connect to DB');
    }

    return $this->con;
}
```